# Get Column with Max Index Across a Group in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following Data in a Pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['AAA','2019-01-01', 10], ['AAA','2019-01-02', 21],
        ['AAA','2019-02-01', 30], ['AAA','2019-02-02', 45],
        ['BBB','2019-01-01', 50], ['BBB','2019-01-02', 60],
        ['BBB','2019-02-01', 70],['BBB','2019-02-02', 80]]

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NAME', 'TIMESTAMP','VALUE'])

  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80
```

Is it possible to create a column which returns the maximum value of the 'Index' across a group (for e.g. NAME), so the expected output is as follows:

```
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE MAXIDX
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10    3
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21    3
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30    3
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45    3
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50    7
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60    7
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70    7
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80    7
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can groupby and transform for idxmax, eg:

```
dfx['MAXIDX'] = dfx.groupby('NAME').transform('idxmax')
```

Comment: Hi @Jon, Thank you for your response however, I get the following error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 23, placement implies 1

Comment: @babsdoc if you're going to post the error in a comment... make sure to put backticks around it so it renders

Comment: Thanks Jon, will note that.

Comment: @JonClements probably `dfx.groupby('NAME').VALUE.transform('idxmax')`. Otherwise, you would get a dataframe on the right-hand-side and assignment would fail as indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you can use reset_index() together with groupby and then merge it into the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['AAA','2019-01-01', 10], ['AAA','2019-01-02', 21],
        ['AAA','2019-02-01', 30], ['AAA','2019-02-02', 45],
        ['BBB','2019-01-01', 50], ['BBB','2019-01-02', 60],
        ['BBB','2019-02-01', 70],['BBB','2019-02-02', 80]]

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NAME', 'TIMESTAMP','VALUE'])

dfx = dfx.reset_index(drop=False)
dfx = dfx.merge(dfx.groupby('NAME',as_index=False).agg({'index':'max'}),how='left',on='NAME').rename(columns={'index_y':'max_index'}).drop(columns='index_x')
```

Output:

```
NAME    TIMESTAMP   VALUE   max_index
 AAA    2019-01-01     10           3
 AAA    2019-01-02     21           3
 AAA    2019-02-01     30           3
 AAA    2019-02-02     45           3
 BBB    2019-01-01     50           7
 BBB    2019-01-02     60           7
 BBB    2019-02-01     70           7
 BBB    2019-02-02     80           7
```

Comment: Thanks @Celius, I got an idea when you mentioned the reset index, here is what I did dfx.reset_index(drop=False)
dfx['MAXIDX'] = dfx.groupby('NAME')['index'].transform(max) , this works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following code solved my problem for me, thanks to @Jon and @Celius.

```
dfx.reset_index(drop=False)
dfx['MAXIDX'] = dfx.groupby('NAME')['index'].transform(max)
```

Comment: Cheers, easier than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I will do `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates` + `merge`

```
df.merge(df.sort_values('VALUE').
         drop_duplicates('NAME',keep='last')['NAME'].
         reset_index(),on='NAME')
Out[73]: 
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE  index
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10      3
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21      3
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30      3
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45      3
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50      7
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60      7
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70      7
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80      7
```